# Was 'ActiveX Scripting' step type secretly removed from SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, jobs, scripting

Migrating our database from SQL Server 2012 to 2016, we can't recreate an SQL Agent job that involves an ActiveX Scripting step written in VBScript.

The error message suggests that `'ACTIVESCRIPTING'` is not an allowed value for the `@subsystem` parameter of `sp_add_jobstep`.

I know ActiveX Scripting is marked as "will be removed in ***a*** future version of SQL Server". However I cannot see anything about it actually being removed in ***this*** version of SQL Server.

SQL Server documentation seems to suggest it is still available in SQL Server 2016:

- [Create an ActiveX Script Job Step (SQL Server 2016)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-an-activex-script-job-step)
- [Documentation on `sp_add_jobstep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-jobstep-transact-sql), updated in March 2017, still lists `@subsystem ='ACTIVESCRIPTING'` as available.

Was `@subsystem ='ACTIVESCRIPTING'` in fact secretly removed in an undocumented way, or did we miss an installable component that enables it?

Comment: Added a comment on Microsoft's `sp_add_jobstep` page noting the discontinuing of `ACTIVESCRIPTING` as of SQL 2016.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server-2016) indicates

> ```
> ActiveX subsytem is discontinued. Use command line or PowerShell scripts instead.
> ```